# How to retrieve response from xmlhttprequest? (screenshots)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, response

I've got this code of autocomplete jqueryUI:

```
.autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
  var results = $.getJSON( url, {
    term: extractLast( request.term )
  }, response );      
  console.log(results);
},...
```

The console.log of the var 'results' looks like this:
[image]

I need to extract the response or responseText field to test if is empty and popup an error with no matches found. But nothing works to retrieve that field:

```
results.response
results.getResponse()
results.getResponseHeader()
```

Neither of these methods works. Thanks

Both of the answers work: It returns my response properly. I can test it.. but it break my autocomplete. I am still looking into it.

> The third variation, the callback, provides the most flexibility, and can be used to connect any data source to Autocomplete. The callback gets two arguments:
>
> A request object, with a single property called "term", which refers
> to the value currently in the text input. For example, when the user
> entered "new yo" in a city field, the Autocomplete term will equal
> "new yo".
>
> A response callback, which expects a single argument to
> contain the data to suggest to the user. This data should be filtered
> based on the provided term, and can be in any of the formats described
> above for simple local data (String-Array or Object-Array with
> label/value/both properties). It's important when providing a custom
> source callback to handle errors during the request. You must always
> call the response callback even if you encounter an error. This
> ensures that the widget always has the correct state.

This is the jquery UI autocomplete documentation about source by callback function. I can't understand why the new version is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the response you probably want to do

```
var results = $.getJSON( url, {
    term: extractLast( request.term )
}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: it works for testing.. but it breaks my autocomplete.. no options dropdown now :(

Comment: @alex anything pop up in the console?

Answer (score 1):

[.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getjson/) is asynchronous and will return the result in a callback function.

Hence, change your code to something like this:

```
.autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        var results = $.getJSON( url, {
            term: extractLast( request.term )
        }, function( results ) {
            console.log( results );
        });      
    }, ...
);
```

If you by some reason need to do a synchronous call you can use jQuery's [.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function instead with the `async` option set to false.

Answer (score 0):

You need a success callback when performing jQuery's ajax functions. You should read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).